# How to make a plot from method read_html of Pandas on Python 2.7?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a plot (whichever) and cannot see method .plot() and also i'm getting this traceback: (The data is a print of df)

```
[                       2019      I     II    III IV
Total                                              
3373           Barrio1   1175   1117   1081  Â
8079             Barrio2   2651   2570   2858  Â
3839        Barrio232      1364   1237   1238  Â
1762              Barrio2342342       544    547    671  Â
3946   Barrio224235      1257   1291   1398  Â
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/str_leu/Documents/PycharmProjects/flask/graphs.py", line 13, in <module>
    plt.scatter(df['barrios'], df['leuros'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and the code is:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

table = BeautifulSoup(open('./PycharmProjects/flask/tables.html', 'r').read(), features="lxml").find('table')


df = pandas.read_html(str(table), decimal=',', thousands='.', index_col=0)

print df

plt.scatter(df['barrios'], df['euros'])

plt.show()
```

**UPDATED**

```
df = pandas.read_html(str(table), decimal=',', thousands='.', index_col=2, header=1)
```

At the end i found how to deal with it but the problem is the last column (strange character) anyone know how to skip it?

**UPDATED2**

```
[               District2352  1.175  1.117  1.081     Unnamed: 5
3.373                                                      
8079            District23422   2651   2570   2858     NaN
3839            District7678   1364   1237   1238      NaN
1762            Distric3    544    547    671         NaN
3946            dISTRICT1   1257   1291   1398        NaN
```

Need to drop last column (entire) but dont know the process to pass from read_html method of pandas to DataFrame and then draw a plot...

**UPDATED 3**

```
                     2019      I     II    III  IV
Total                                              
3373            dISTRICT1   1175   1117   1081 NaN
8079            District2   2651   2570   2858 NaN
```

This is an example with the headers

Comment: I think means that columns `barrios` and/or `euros` contain non-numeric data. Use  `df['barrios'].dtype` to see if this is the case. If your data is numeric then this should work I believe.

Comment: I'm sorry but doesn't exist .dtype, how it could be possible?

Comment: For a `pd.DataFrame`, you can use either `.dtype` or `.dtypes` on a column, or `.dtypes` on the entire dataframe. If that doesn't work, there may be an issue with your pandas installation

Comment: Updated the question, i can see the dtypes, thanks, but still looking for to draw a plot from set of dataframes (pandas.read_html method returns it)

Comment: is `barrios` the name of a column or the dataframe? Your `df` is currently a list of dataframes?

Comment: barrios is not a name of a column, is a name that i put to name all the districts (Y axis),'leuros' is to name X axis

Comment: What are the columns names from each `df` you want to plot? `pd.read_html` returns a list, you can't access the elements using strings. Then for each df in your list, you need to access a column to plot it. Can you show a formatted example of one of the dataframes, including all column names and the columns you would like to plot.

Comment: I did it on UPDATED 3, thanks for your interest

Comment: And what are the names of the columns would you like to plot for each dataframe?

Comment: All of them, as much as i can, what i want is to make a plot of entire table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207341/discussion-between-josmoor98-and-m-mariscal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
dfs = pandas.read_html(str(table), decimal=',', thousands='.', header=1, index_col=1, encoding='utf-8').pop(0)

print dfs

x=[]
y=[]
y1=[]
y2=[]

for i, row in dfs.iterrows():
    x.append(row[0])
    y.append(int(row[1]))
    y1.append(int(row[2]))
    y2.append(int(row[3]))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.read_html` returns a list of DataFrames. Currently you're trying to access the list using an `str`, which is causing the error. Depending on your requirements, you can either plot columns from each using a for loop, or combine the dataframes in someway using `pd.concat`

```
import seaborn as sns

# If each dataframe holds the same columns you want to plot
dfs = pandas.read_html(str(table), decimal=',', thousands='.', index_col=0)

for df in dfs: 

    # you would need to individually define the plot you want
    df["2019"].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
    df.plot(x='I', y='II') # etc

    # you could also try seaborn's pairplot. This will omit categorical data
    sns.pairplot(df)
```

Comment: df[2019] crashes, must be integer but takes it as string, also crashes with [{}].format(2019)

Comment: If `2019` is a string, then use `df['2019']`. I assumed it was an integer. Try `df.columns = [str(col) for col in df]` to convert all column names to strings

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: If you followed the code above, `df` is a dataframe which does have an attribute `columns`.

Comment: 2019 is the name of the column, i dont mind if its integer or string, dont want to make it crash jaja